# How to take information from three columns in a spreadsheet and put it into one column on another under a new column name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have one spread sheet listed by SKU that has three different columns, Image Color, Size, Pack. (There are other columns but they are unimportant at the moment) I need this information moved to another spreadsheet that is still listed by SKU but SKUs are listed multiple times with the information from the three columns moved into one column and renamed Family. The end result needs to be in Excel but if I need to involve Access, I'm ok with that.

Comment: Can you offer a bit more detail, perhaps with a brief data example of the source and target after the move. Also, are you asking about a one-time copy/move method, or are you wanting to create and automated process?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull values into your destination sheet using **VLOOKUP()** It looks for a value that you provide in the first column of some range. If it finds the lookup value, then it returns data some number of columns to the right.

```
  | A     B                C
----------------------------------
1 | SKU   Image            Color
2 | 1842  images\1842.png  Cyan
3 | 5532  images\5532.png  Magenta
```

**=VLOOKUP(1842,A1:C3,3,FALSE)** returns *"Cyan"*

You can concatenate multiple values by sticking an ampersand between them.

**=B2&C2** returns *"images\1842.pngCyan"*

You can get what you want by combining these two techniques.
**=VLOOKUP(1842,A1:C3,2,FALSE)&VLOOKUP(1842,A1:C3,3,FALSE)** also returns *"images\1842.pngCyan"*

Ok. Time to put it all together. If your first lookup value in the destination sheet is in cell G2, then you would use (I made it into CSV with &","&)

> =VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$F$8,2,FALSE)&","&VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$F$8,3,FALSE)&","&VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$F$8,4,FALSE)&","&VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$F$8,5,FALSE)

[image]